# How to broadcast vectors (lists) into tuples in Julia?

Tags: julia

Is there a generator/iterator function that will turn

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,4]
```

into `[(1,3),(2,4)]` and

```
a = 1
b = [3,4]
```

into `[(1,3),(1,4)]` using the same expression?

Is there a similar way to create a named tuple such as `[(a=1,b=3),(a=1,b=4)]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use broadcasting with Julia's dot syntax for this:

```
julia> tuple.(a, b)
2-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 3)
 (2, 4)
```

`tuple` here is a function that just creates a tuple from its arguments.

For `NamedTuple`s you can either call the lower-level constructor directly on tuples with

```
julia> NamedTuple{(:a, :b)}.(tuple.(a, b))
2-element Array{NamedTuple{(:a, :b),Tuple{Int64,Int64}},1}:
 (a = 1, b = 3)
 (a = 2, b = 4)
```

where `:a` and `:b` are the sorted key names, or equivalently, using an anonymous function:

```
julia> broadcast((a_i, b_i) -> (a=a_i, b=b_i), a, b)
2-element Array{NamedTuple{(:a, :b),Tuple{Int64,Int64}},1}:
 (a = 1, b = 3)
 (a = 2, b = 4)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Just broadcast the `tuple` function.

```
julia> a = [1,2]; b=[3,4];


julia> tuple.(a,b)
2-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 3)
 (2, 4)

julia> tuple.(1, b)
2-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 3)
 (1, 4)
```

Second question - broadcast the constructor:

```
julia> NamedTuple{(:a, :b)}.(tuple.(1, b))
2-element Array{NamedTuple{(:a, :b),Tuple{Int64,Int64}},1}:
 (a = 1, b = 3)
 (a = 1, b = 4)
```